# Child and Parent Pages list of sub pages

Tags: php, pages, child-pages, children

I have a parent page called services with children, each service child has child pages within it.

On the first level child page i want to show all of the pages below it in.  When i click through to one of those pages, i want that same menu to display, with all of the pages that are the same level as the one i am on showing.

i currently have this code:

```
    global $post;
$subpages = wp_list_pages( array(
    'echo'=>0,
    'title_li'=>'',
    'depth'=>1,
    'child_of'=> ( $post->post_parent == 0 ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent)
));
if ( !empty($subpages) ) {
?>
<div class="services-sub-menu"> 
<?php
    if ( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
        echo '<p class="parent-link"><a href="'. get_permalink($post- 
>post_parent) .'"><em>'. __('Back to') .' '. get_the_title($post- 
 >post_parent) .'</em></a><p>';
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    echo $subpages;
    echo '</ul>';

    ?>

</div>

<?php
} else {

}
```

This works in that is shows the current level sub items.  However, on first level children i want to show the children below, on second level children i want to show children on the same level.

Thankyou in advance for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work out what page level you are on first, so that you know the correct ID to pass to the `child_of` argument of `wp_list_pages`. Give this a try:

```
global $post;
$page_level = 0;
$post_parent = null;

// Work out what page level we're on
if($post->post_parent > 0) {
    $post_parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
    $page_level = ($post_parent->post_parent == 0 ? 1 : 2);
}

// Updated with page IDs
echo 'Current page: '.$post->ID.'<br />';
echo 'Current parent: '.$post->post_parent.'<br />';
echo 'Current level'.$page_level.'<br />';
echo 'Loading pages from '.($page_level == 2 ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'<br />';

$subpages = wp_list_pages(array(
    'echo'     =>0,
    'title_li' =>'',
    'depth'    =>1,
    'child_of' => ($page_level == 2 ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID)
));


if ( !empty($subpages) ) {
?>
<div class="services-sub-menu"> 
<?php
    if ( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
        echo '<p class="parent-link"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->post_parent) .'"><em>'. __('Back to') .' '. get_the_title($post->post_parent) .'</em></a><p>';
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    echo $subpages;
    echo '</ul>';

    ?>

</div>

<?php
} else {

}
```

Comment: This works for the first level of child pages, but then i have nothing on the second level, with my code i have the right menu on the second level and the wrong one on the first level...

Comment: Can you update your post with the IDs of each page from the WP admin (top level, level 1 and level 2) and then echo out the IDs using my updated answer? I just ran the test on a local installation and got the correct nesting of pages.

Comment: Just tried again and i must have left some rogue PHP in, this has done the job perfectly.

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working for you.

Comment: Thankyou for your help :)